# Magento 2: How to move Product page Attributes Section from tabs to Bottom of page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I saw a similar question for moving reviews tab.
but I want to move the attributes - `additional.tab` as well outside tabs.
I tried the same code like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- add this code -->
         <move element="additional.tab" destination="content" after="-"/>
    <!-- end -->
    </body>
</page>
```

but it's not having any effect.

though if I try `reviews.tab` it is getting duplicated at the end of page, without moving it.

I am using Magento 2.2.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="product.attributes" destination="content" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="product.info.details" destination="content.aside" after="product.info.upsell"/>
    </body>
</page>
```